# Razor-pages - Dynamically Switch css background / theme

Tags: html, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

Question:
How to dynamically change div class / theme.
From 'nul' to 'bg-info' to 'bg-success'

i.e:

```
<div class="container body-content">
<div class="container body-content bg-info">
<div class="container body-content bg-success">
```

(Razor-pages 2.1.1 / Visual Studio 2017 / EF 2.1.1)
(bootstrap - no controller structure)

Setup: EF / localDB to switch or list options.

Used VS Template:
C# > .Net Core > .Net Core Web Application > Razor-pages

Answer (score 1):

MyPage.cshtml:

```
@page
@using MyProject.Pages
@model MyPageModel

<div class="container body-content@Model.Theme">
```

MyPage.cshtml.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System;

namespace MyProject.Pages
{
    public class MyPageModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Theme { get; set; } = "";

        public void OnGet()
        {
            if(showInfo) Theme = "bg-info";
            else if(showInfo) Theme = "bg-success";
        }
    }
}
```